# range end index 16388 out of range for slice of length 16384

Tags: ink, weight

## Code

I defined a field in my contract like this

```
messages: Mapping<String, Vec<Message>>
```

Message is struct

```
pub struct Message {
    pub id: u128,
    pub key: String,
    pub p: String,
    pub b: String,
    pub s: Vec<String>,
    pub addr: AccountId,
    pub sel: [u8;4],
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
}
```

This is a method with pseudo-code

```
fn push_message(&mut self, message: Message) -> Result<(), Error> {
            let mut c_message = self.messages.get(&message.key).unwrap_or(Vec::<Message>::new());
            c_message.push(message);
            self.received_message_table.insert(message.key, &c_message);
            Ok(())
}
```

## Operation

Repeatedly call `push_message` with the same `key` value to test the upper limit of Vec size.

## Expectation

I can call `push_message` successfully every time until the weight exceeds the maxExtrinsic weight.

## Result

I only pushed 67 message into the Vec, then I got the error `contracts.ContractTraped`.
In the node terminal, I saw the output "range end index 16388 out of range for slice of length 16384".

What does this mean?
I think the transaction fail is because of the storage limit, instead of gas limit, is it?

Comment: 4 bytes sounds like a `Compact<u32>` at the start... if the len were really small it would take 1 byte. https://docs.rs/parity-scale-codec/3.1.5/src/parity_scale_codec/codec.rs.html#1044-1050

Comment: Please post the complete error from the node console.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem is that ink! internally uses a static buffer to avoid expensive heap allocations. The limitation of this static buffer is 16 KiB, which is 16384 bytes, so the limit that you are hitting:

https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/env/src/engine/on_chain/buffer.rs#L22-L23

The limit was originally chosen to be ideal for the underlying database used in Substrate. There have been changes in the meantime now though, so that we're contemplating increasing the limit. There is also an open PR for ink! to make this limit configurable: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1279.

What I want to question though is why you are pushing the `Message` in its entirety to the `Vec`. It's typically an anti-pattern for smart contracts to use big vectors, as many operations become more gas-expensive on them instead of on e.g. a `Mapping`.

Could you use something along those lines, for example?

```rust
messages: Mapping<String, Vec<MessageId>>
messageid_to_message: Mapping<MessageId, Message>
```

This would decrease the amount stored in the `Vec` significantly.